Are there other Quantum Chips that operate at room temperature other than Plasmonic-enabled CMOS devices?
Are there any other Quantum Chips that operate at room temperature other thanPlasmonic-enabled CMOS devices? https://zephyrnet.com/unexpected-quantum-leap-in-the-cloud-race-a-dive-into-spectral-capital-otcqbfccn/

The hardware for cold neutral atom quantum computers operate at room temperature. The atoms themselves are cooled using lasers, but no cryogenic machinery is needed.
